# Magento adminhtml custom (customer) tab add fields correct

Tags: magento, module, magento-1.9

I want to add a custom tab to the edit customer page.
Now that is not a problem.
But i wondered, is there a perfect way to add input fields in that tab?
Because every tutorial uses a phtml file where you add code yourself.
But is it possible to fill this tab programmatically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A quick google search yields this.  Seems like it would work:http://www.nextbits.eu/blog/how-to-add-tab-in-customer-information-in-magento-admin/

Comment: Thanks @espradley, so we'll use the plain phtml file :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i searched for way to long i tried to just load in an block that creates a form.
So i simply loaded that block and it was done.
No html just clean magento code:

In your phtml file:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/adminhtml_dir_blockname')->toHtml();
```

And offcourse your block:

```
<?php

class Foo_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Dir_Blockname extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $network = Mage::registry('yourdata');
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('blockname_form', array(
            'legend' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('name')
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Name'),
            'required' => true,
        ));

        $this->setForm($form);
        $form->setValues($network);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont think you can do this without a template file especially you want to add a completely custom tab.

regards

-David

Comment: Thanks :)  
And i don't mind adding a template file. But like system.xml i thought there would be an easier/cleaner way to do this. If not, no problem.  
Just wanted to know.  
  
ps. when i get no other answer within 2 days i will accept this one as a the answer ;)